# What is $q$ in the factorized form $a(x+p)^2 + q$ of a quadratic equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I can't put the following equation into $a(x+p)^2 + q$ form:

$$-4x^2 - 2x + 3$$

I've gotten as far as: $-4(x + (\frac{1}{4})^2)$, but what would $q$ be? I got $\frac{1}{4}$ by the fact that $p = \frac{b}{2}.$

Comment: Compare $-4\color{red}{x^2}-2\color{red}{x}+3$ with $a(x+p)^2+q=a\color{red}{x^2}+2ap\color{red}{x}+(ap^2+q)$ to get $$a=-4, \qquad 2ap=-2, \qquad ap^2+q=3.$$ Now solve for $p,q$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the factor of $-4$ from the first 2 terms to get $$-4\left(x^2 + \frac{1}{2}x \right) + 3 $$

Now note that $$x^2 + \frac{1}{2}x = \left(x + \frac{1}{4}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2$$ Then put this all together to get $$-4x^2 - 2x + 3 = -4\left[\left(x + \frac{1}{4}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^2\right] + 3$$ which simplifies to $$-4x^2 - 2x + 3 = -4\left(x + \frac{1}{4}\right)^2 + \frac{13}{4}$$
and so $a = -4$, $p = \frac{1}{4}$ and $q = \frac{13}{4}$.

This is the method of [completing the square](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/completing-square.html).

The value of $q$ represents the $y$ coordinate of the turning point on the curve $y= -4x^2 - 2x + 3$

---

**Alternative 1:** you could take out the factor of $-4$ from all three terms, but this would lead to messier fractions.

---

**Alternative 2:** you could write $$-4x^2 -2x + 3 \equiv a(x+p)^2 + q $$ and expanding the RHS gives $$-4x^2 -2x + 3 \equiv ax^2 + 2apx + (ap^2 + q)$$ Then you can compare coefficients and this will give you some equations to solve for the values of $a$, $p$ and $q$